# Django - how to add conditional drop down in templates from database

Tags: html, ajax, django, django-templates

I am new to django. I need to put conditional drop-down on my web app based on the radio button selected by user in form. The idea is that based on radio button selection by user another drop-down should be populated on the form. This drop down will be a from a list of values that will be retrieved from database. The final value selected from this drop-down will do the main operation by pressin separate buttons. Please suggest how to do that. An example or link will surely help. Thanks

My example  code is

```
<script>
    function my_radio_select() {
    var1 = document.getElementById("radio1");
    var2 = document.getElementById("radio2");
    var3 = document.getElementById("radio3");
    if (var1.checked === true) {
        window.location.href = "A.html";
    }
    else if(var2.checked === true) {
        window.location.href = "A.html";
        document.myform.action = "A.html";
    }
    else if(var3.checked === true) {
        window.location.href = "A.html";
    }
}
    </script>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="project_type" value=0 checked onclick="my_radio_select();">
    <label>Projects I own</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="project_type" value=1 onclick="my_radio_select();">
    <label>Projects I manage</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="project_type" value=1 onclick="my_radio_select();">
    <label>Projects I can edit</label>
{% endblock %}

class MyProjForm(ModelForm):
    existing_projs = CSProj.objects.all()
    choices_int = tuple((p.name, p.name) for p in existing_projs)
    #tech = forms.ChoiceField(label='Existing Projects' ,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),choices=choices_int,required=True)
    tech = forms.ChoiceField(label='Existing Projects' ,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),choices=choices_int,required=False)

    class Meta:
         model = CSProj
         fields = ['name','user_workspace', 'compiler_path','ccs_path','tdk_path']
         exclude = ('name','user_workspace', 'compiler_path','ccs_path','tdk_path')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'user' in kwargs:
            user = kwargs.pop('user')

        super(MyProjForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ### Done to refresh choices as soon as it is added
        existing_projs = CSProj.objects.filter(owner_id=user)
        choices_int = tuple((p.name, p.name) for p in existing_projs)
        self.fields['tech'].choices=choices_int
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do all the stuff without reloading the page you need to use `AJAX`. `Django` will only render the form for you.

1. Render all the required fields in a form (or two forms).
2. Hide those fields (or forms) that should appear only if the radio button is checked (Using `JS, jQuery`).
3. Show the hidden stuff and get the necessary values from db using ajax as the radio button is checked.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I am very new to this domain. I don't have an idea. If you can tell some example that will surely help. Appreciate you reply

Comment: @user3364086 don't accept an answer until you are happy with the answer!! else they will just leave it..

Comment: Please, show the form you have, marking fields that you want to appear if the radio button is checked - i'll make an example for you.

Comment: What I want is that if a radio button is checked then a drop -dwon should be populated and should appear on page. This drop-down will have different values based on different radio button option. I can do it in 2 ways either have a default drop -down based on default radio button selection and then dynamically update it other option is selected. I am not sure what is the correct place to add this check and how...Thanks

Comment: I understood what you want. I ask you just to post here what you have (template and forms.py).

Comment: do i need to ask a separate question...replying to  comment has character limit...sorry for borthering...I am new to this site as well

Comment: Thanks I found and have just done that...Appreciate all your help

Comment: Right now even if I click on this link I am not allowed to chat...Please edit my code...Thanks